# Calculate $f'(x)$, where $f(x)=\int_0^x\cos(2x)\sin(2t)\,dt$

Tags: calculus

I need to find $f'(x)$, where 
$$f(x)=\int_0^x\cos(2x)\sin(2t)\,dt.$$
I'm really not sure how to do it.

Comment: Just apply this:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, on this site we use MathJaX to format our maths. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/145141) you can find a basic tutorial.

Comment: Or you just integrate with respect to $t$ like normal, then differentiate.

Answer (score 2):

Since the integrand functions are continuous, we can apply the fundamental theorem of calculus and get a primitive:

$$\int_0^x\sin 2t\;dt=F(x)-F(0)=F(x)\;,\;\;\text{with}\;\;F'(t)=\sin 2t$$

I know it is easy to find out explicitly $\;F\;$ but this more general way can be helpful in other, more difficult cases. Thus we get:

$$f(x)=\int_0^x\cos2x\sin2t\;dt=\cos2x\int_0^x\sin2t\;dt=\cos2x\,F(x)\implies$$

$$\implies f'(x)=-2\sin2x\,F(x)+\cos2xF'(x)=-2\sin2x\,F(x)+\overbrace{\sin2x\cos2x}^{=\frac12\sin4x}$$

If you want more explicitly then do finally write

$$\;F(x)=\int_0^x\sin2t\;dt=\left.-\frac12\cos2t\right|_0^x\;=-\frac12\cos2x+\frac12$$

and finally

$$f'(x)=-2\sin2x\left(-\frac12\cos2x+\frac12\right)+\sin2x\cos2x=$$

$$=2\sin2x\cos2x-\sin2x=\sin4x-\sin2x$$